# Print image with alt text

Tags: theming, 8, media

In the node template, I print an image gallery. I need to add the *alt* text.

```
<div class="field--name-field_gallery">
  {{ content.field_gallery }}
  {{ content.field_gallery.alt_field }}
</div>
```

There are many images, which are printed, but the *alt* text is not printed.

How can I print it?

Answer (score 0):

Print the image field in the node template like any other field:

`{{ content.field_gallery }}`

And then use a field twig to loop through multiple field items:

field--field-gallery.html.twig

```
 <div class="row expanded">
  {% for item in items %}
     {{ item.content }}
     {{ item.alt }}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Comment: I have not  tried it yet, but I think it should work. Thank you